# appsheet prevent duplicate entries

Tags: google-sheets, mobile-application, google-appsheet

I would like to know how I can prevent a duplicate entry (based on my own client/project definition of what that means-below), in an AppSheet mobile app connected to Google Sheets.
AppSheet talks alot about UNIQUEID() which they also encourage using and designating as the KEY field.  row_number is another possibility.
This is fine for the KEY in the sense of its purpose is to be unique, meaningless, and uniquely identify a record, and relate to other tables.

However, it doesn't prevent a duplicate ("duplicate" again, as defined by my own client's business rules&process) from occurring.  I mean, I assume the UniqueId() theoretically would, but that's abstract theory, because it would only produce unique ones anyway.

MY TABLE HAS THESE COLUMN:  [FACILITY NUMBER] and [TIMESTAMP] (date and time of event).  We consider it a duplicate event, and want to DISALLOW the adding of such a record to this table, if the 2nd record has the same DATE (time irrelevant), with the same FACILITY.  (we just do one facility per day, ever).

In AppSheet how can I create some logic that disallows the add based on that criteria?  I even basically know some ways I would do it.  it just seems like I can't find a place to "put" it.  I created an expression that perfectly evalutes to TRUE or FALSE and nothing else, (by referencing whether or not the FACILIY NUMBER on the new record being added is in a SLICE which I've defined as today's entries). I wanted to place this expression in another (random) field's VALIDIF.  To me it seemed like that would meet the platform documentation.  the other random field would be considered valid, only if the expression evaluated to true.  but instead appsheet thought i wanted to conver the entire [other random column] to a dependent dropdown.

Please help!  I will cry tears of joy when appsheet introduces FORM events and RECORD events that can be hooked into at the time of keying, saving, etc.

Answer (score 3):

surprised to see this question here in stackoverflow --- most AppSheet questions are at http://community.appsheet.com. 
The brief answer is that you are doing the right thing providing a Valid_If constraint. Your constraint is of the form IN([_THIS], ) so AppSheet is doing the "smart" thing by automatically converting that list into a dropdown of allowed values. From your post, it appears that you may instead want to say NOT(IN([_THIS], )) -- thereby saying that the value [_THIS] is valid as long as it is not in the list specified (making sure it is not a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but in case someone stumbles upon the same:

The (not so simple) answer is given in https://help.appsheet.com/en/articles/961274-list-expressions-and-aggregates.

From the reference:

> NOT(IN([_THIS], SELECT(Customers[State], NOT(IN([CustomerId],
> LIST([_THISROW].[CustomerId])))))): when used as the Valid_If
> condition for the State column, it ensures that every customer has a
> unique value for State. In this example, we assume that CustomerId is
> the key for the Customers table.

This could be written more schematic like this:

```
NOT(IN([_THIS], SELECT(<TableName>[<UnqiueColumnName>], NOT(IN([<KeyColumnName>], LIST([_THISROW].[<KeyColumnName>]))))))
```

Technically it says:

1. Get me a list of the current values of the column  of the table
2. Ignore the value of the current row (identified by [_THISROW] and looking into the  column)
3. Check, if the given value exists in the resulting list

This statement has to be defined - with the correct values for , &  - as Valid_If statement.